# Resources to learn about memory allocation & security

Tags: memory

Are there any good online resources to pick up knowledge about how memory allocations affect security?

Its a new area for me, and any pointers on where to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase because I am not sure what you are asking. Can you link to an example of what you are wondering about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw what you did there, asking about memory allocation & security then mentioning pointers ;)

In my opinion, the best way to start off learning about memory (in general) is to write code. I'm not sure there is any other way of approaching this. Not just any code, find a language which forces memory management on the programmer, no managed environments such as Java or the .NET Framework. These are great languages for RAD, but don't provide the lower level aspects that would be required. I recommend C or C++. Learn about pointers, dangling references, dynamic memory allocation & deallocation, etc.

Assembly is a fantastic language if you want to learn the ins and outs of how software runs, but it also is hella-difficult to understand. You don't necessarily need to be able to write assembly code, though. Just pickup a few documents on the language and I guarantee you'll increase your understanding of memory substantially.

Sometimes the only way to truly understand how something works, is to take it apart. Pick up a book on operating system architecture such as [Operating Systems - Design and Implementation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136386776) or a reverse engineering book [Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764574817). Take some stuff apart, become familiar with a debugger and analyze applications running in memory. Start toying around with breakpoints and see what your debugger tells you about whats going on.

In conclusion, the best way in my opinion to learn about memory is to be responsible for managing it. Start off slow, learn C++ and work towards harder stuff.

http://www.cprogramming.com/debuggers.html

Answer (score 2):

[Buffer Overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) might be what you are trying to refer to. Once you figure out exactly what it is you want to learn, you may want to build your own testing environment to observe how it works. [DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/) is a great place to start with that.

Answer (score 1):

The memory allocator may influence security in the following way: the choice of memory allocator may affect the ease or difficulty of exploiting buffer overrun and other memory-safety-related vulnerabilities.

For instance, randomizing the location at which objects are allocated can disrupt exploits that rely upon these objects to be at predictable locations -- thus defeating the attacker.  Thus, a well-designed memory allocator can play a role in implementing ASLR ([address-space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR)).  In general, a memory allocator can potentially help defend against some "heap exploits".

See, e.g., the following research papers for some work on building hardened memory allocators that make it harder to exploit these kinds of vulnerabilities:

- [DieHard: Probabilistic Memory Safety for Unsafe Languages](http://www.cs.umass.edu/%7Eemery/pubs/fp014-berger.pdf), Emery D. Berger and Benjamin G. Zorn, PLDI 2006.  This paper designs a memory allocator that randomizes the layout of objects on the heap, thus making it harder to exploit certain security vulnerabilities.  See the [Diehard project page](http://plasma.cs.umass.edu/emery/diehard) for more information.  Apparently, [this work influenced the design](http://emeryblogger.com/2010/04/06/winning-the-war-on-bugs/) of similar mitigations in the [Windows 7 Fault-Tolerant Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744764%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
- [DieHarder: Securing the Heap](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/UM-CS-2010-033.pdf), Gene Novark, Emery D. Berger, ACM CCS 2010.  DieHarder improves upon DieHard by providing better security against certain attacks.
- [Cling: A Memory Allocator to Mitigate Dangling Pointers](http://www.usenix.org/event/sec10/tech/full_papers/Akritidis.pdf), Periklis Akritidis, Usenix Security 2010.  Cling is a memory allocator intended to make it harder to exploit use-after-free vulnerabilities.
- [Kernel Pool Exploitation on Windows 7](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-dc-11/Mandt/BlackHat_DC_2011_Mandt_kernelpool-wp.pdf), Tarjei Mandt, Blackhat 2011.  The Windows 7 kernel's memory allocator was designed to try to stop exploitation of certain kinds of memory-safety vulnerabilities.  This paper finds that the protection is imperfect and describes how an attacker could defeat the protection under certain conditions.

Here's some more information about how deployed operating systems are implementing these ideas:

- [A new malloc(3) for OpenBSD](http://openbsd.org/papers/eurobsdcon2009/otto-malloc.pdf).  This slide deck explains how the OpenBSD memory allocator was changed to use randomization.
- The [Windows 7 Fault-Tolerant Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744764%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) implements some of these ideas (as mentioned above).